# MySQL annoying syntax error on CREATE TABLE with data values tinytext, longtext, and enum

Tags: php, mysql

My code is as follows:

```
$sql = "
    CREATE TABLE articles (
        articleUID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        PRIMARY KEY(articleUID), 
        by tinytext, 
        article longtext, 
        game enum('Starcraft','Starcraft 2','Team Fortress 2','Minecraft','Tekkit','other')
    )
";
if(mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
    echo "The table \"articles\" was created succesfully.<br />";
} else{
    echo "Error creating  table: " . mysql_error() . "<br />";
}
```

It's in PHP, and there is other stuff to the file, but this is the part that's giving me problems.

When I try to run this, all I get is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'by tinytext, article longtext, game enum(Starcraft,Starcraft 2,Team Fortress 2,' at line 1
```

I don't know if you need the rest of my code to solve this, but if you do I'll post it in an edit. Can anyone tell me what's wrong here? I've tried it using \" in place of ' on the enum arguments, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

`BY` is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and must be quoted with backticks when used as a column or table identifier.

You can declare the primary key right inside the column definition:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE articles (
  articleUID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  /* Quote the reserved word BY */
  `by` tinytext, 
  article longtext, 
  game enum('Starcraft','Starcraft 2','Team Fortress 2','Minecraft','Tekkit','other')
)";
```

Alternatively, you can declare the `PRIMARY KEY` after the column definition, with the parenthetical

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE articles (
  articleUID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `by` tinytext, 
  article longtext, 
  game enum('Starcraft','Starcraft 2','Team Fortress 2','Minecraft','Tekkit','other'),
  PRIMARY KEY (articleUID)
)";
```

Answer (score 2):

`by` is a keyword in mysql. If you dont want to use it as a keyword, quote it. Also you have an error when defining auto increment and primary key.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE articles (
    `articleUID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `by` tinytext, 
    `article longtext,
    `game` enum('Starcraft','Starcraft 2','Team Fortress 2','Minecraft','Tekkit','other')
)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put you primary key definition in between your column definitions. Declare all your columns first, then your primary key at the end.